# "Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027haha\u0027

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm a newbie in Jquery Ajax. I need your help. I want to display one text beside span element. I have already done reference some topics but i cant resolve it

Here is my error in firebug (newlines and indentation added)

> ```
> {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027haha\u0027.",
>  "StackTrace":"
>    at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>    at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>    at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
>    at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
>  "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
> ```

In aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNoiDung" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txtNoiDung"></asp:TextBox><span id="vltxtNoiDung"></span>
```

In code behind

```
  [WebMethod()]
    public static string test1cai(string haha)
    {
        return haha;
    }
```

In Javascript

```
$(".txtNoiDung").focusout(function () {
        var dataToSend = { names: $(this).val() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "QuanLyTin.aspx/test1cai",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#vltxtNoiDung").text(msg.d)
            },
            error: function (xhr, reason, ex) {
                alert(reason);
            }
        });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),` to

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    haha: $(".txtNoiDung").val()
}),
```

This is assuming that `$(".txtNoiDung")` is unique in the page, if it's not, you'll need another mechanism for getting the value. I'm pretty sure you can get away with `$(this).val())` to get the value in this case.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer by pushing the check-mark button.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name from the method should always be same with parameter passed in the data for an Ajax call.
instead of names in data use haha(parameter from c# method).