# jqGrid inline edit save does not save JSON row

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am struggling already whole week with this and cant find the right solution....

I use inline editing which only uses the keys and mouse for update and editing, however I can get the row to edit and change something, however on enter I am NOT able to save the row to the server nor to catch the row after update (enter).
I have searched everywhere how to fixed this but no logical solution found anywhere.

The code I am using in a seperate function which I call from OnRowSelect:

```
function savedata (id, lastsel, $grd) { 
  lastStatus = $('#_grid_action').val();
  alert(id + ' ' + lastStatus);alert(id + ' ' + lastsel + ' ' + lastStatus );
  if (id === lastsel && lastStatus == 1) {   
     var rowData = $grd.jqGrid("getRowData",id);
     var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(rowData);
     alert('if equal: ' + dataToSend);
  } 
  if (id !== lastsel && lastStatus == '')
  {
     lastStatus = 1;
     $grd.jqGrid('editRow', id, 
       {
          keys : true,
          oneditfunc : function(id) {   
            alert ("edited: " + id); 
          },
          successfunc : function(id) {   
            alert ("succeed");    
            return true;
           },
           url : "dataServices/objects.asmx/InvokeTest",
           extraparam : 
           { 
             'item': 'testedti'
           },
           aftersavefunc : function(id) {   
              alert ("after save");    
              return true;
           },
           errorfunc: null,
           afterrestorefunc : null,
           restoreAfterError : true,
           mtype : "POST"
        });
        lastsel = id; 
        $('#_grid_action').val('1');
      }
 }
```

The main problem is that:
1. After enter the row data disappears in nothing, as I do not find anything anywhere, how this is "automatically" being saved to my webservice and which parameter it uses, as with extraparam I seems to being able to use only for static parameters and not to catch the row data, convert it to JSON and send it to some predefined parameter.
What I actually try to accomplish is to use saverow within the editrow to send the data I want to the server based upon onenter event almost all "func" are there but not something like "beforesavefunc", maybe I am missing something very simple, but I cant find it nowhere

Confirm the documents from Olegs company the editrow should be able to handle the saverow directly as build in which is great (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow).

UPDATE:
I can get now the the with adding to the serializeRowData return { q: JSON.stringify(postData) } but now it give the response I have a Invalid JSON primitive....
Does somebody knows why, as I use JSON.stringify.....

Some help would be appriciated )))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anybody else who is struggling with the same issue, there is a very simple solution to post your complete row data back to the server with using your own parameter on this...
Still really do not understand how others are doing this, but...........

Anyway thanks to [1]: ["Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027haha\u0027](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028532/messageinvalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-u0027haha-u00), I came up with the very simple solution:

```
serializeRowData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify({data: JSON.stringify(postData)}); }, rest of your stuff.
```

Apparantly if you look to the code [2]: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L217 jqGrid does only take the whole string and has no ability to add any parameters there also does not make it a JSON, however this is the solution, hope some of you can save a week with this as I could not find it ))))

Happy coding!!!